# How to simulate typing keyboard keys and <tab> from a BASH script?

Tags: bash, macos, automation

I must enter a lot of data into the forms on a workplace Web site. I already have data in a spreadsheet, but must essentially type in the data manually. I would like to create a BASH script which types in the data into the Web browser to save time.

Is it possible to have a BASH script do things like type keys on the keyboard, such as numbers, and `[tab]`, while focused on my browser window? With this, I could easily create a BASH script which automatically enters the data I need.

The answer in [Is there a way to trigger a Hot Key/Keyboard Shortcut via a Shell Script, a AppleScript or a Automator Workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810703/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-a-hot-key-keyboard-shortcut-via-a-shell-script-a-applseems) useful, but is only for OS X, while I use Debian.

Comment: Maybe try a firefox or desktop automation tool?

Comment: I am not familiar with these. Is there any that can go through CSV data like this and enter it onto the page?

Comment: I believe this will suit you well enough: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/

Comment: I am not doing the same task again and again, as the data in the CSV file is different each time I need to enter data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send key code to command line program on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616015/send-key-code-to-command-line-program-on-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

You can get it importing "Selenium" in java / python... code.
You are interested in method sendKeys.

Here is an example:

```
WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

You can encapsulate Selenium's calls in a small java code that you call from a shell script, keeping the logic in your script.